# hide or remove title field from web part

Tags: web-part, sharepoint-foundation, list-view

Programmatically I created a list which is type of GenericList. in the onet.xml file of my Web template I added following

```
<View List="Lists/MyList" BaseViewID="1" WebPartZoneID="Left" WebPartOrder="1"  />
```

It works but when I go to the page the list shows only the Title column and I have to got to edit webpart and choose default view "All objects" to show my columns.

I have tried to modify the default view, I have tried to add new Content Type and delete alla other content types, I have tried to hide Title, I have tried to delete Title (but failed because it is basetype and cannot delete it), I have tried to create new view and add it as default. but no success. first time I go to the page it shows only Title and I have to edit the web part.

Answer (score 1):

```
SPLimitedWebPartManager mgr = null;

mgr = web.GetLimitedWebPartManager("default.aspx", System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.PersonalizationScope.Shared);

foreach (System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.WebPart wp in mgr.WebParts)
{

 // Check if the webpart title is "Shared Documents"
 if (wp.Title == "Shared Documents")
 {
 //Convert the webpart to list view webpart type 
 ListViewWebPart listWP = (ListViewWebPart)wp;

 if (listWP != null)
 {
     Guid viewID = new Guid(listWP.ViewGuid);
     SPView wpView = list.Views[viewID];

     wpView.ViewFields.Delete("Title");

     // Update the view 
     wpView.Update();
 }
 break;
 }
}
```

This should work...

Ref: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/eu/sharepointdevelopment/thread/ae4c27c8-42ef-4bbf-b6a7-5957f2160835

Comment: thanks, I dont know where do I use your code. Do I need to create a new feature?

in a feature I cannot get default.aspx because it has not been created yet.

Comment: yes I think you need to create a feature and write the code there, I really don't have idea at what point in time you have the default.aspx created...